# Avoid importing and change timestamps

Tags: python

How can I *avoid* using `import`, and make the source file "feel" the changes of a "library"?

The general context: I am **forbidden** using `import` in my code, so I resorted to a trick like this one:

#### `fake_import.py`

```
with open("cool_lib.py") as utils:
    exec(utils.read())
```

This does not play well with other tools I need to use, since any change to `cool_lib.py` won't affect timestamps of `fake_import.py`, and these tools, based on `make`, need to see whether some Python file have been changed.

Now of course I could change every `.py` file by hand or with a script. But I don't like it.

Any useful ideas?

Comment: Forbidden to use `import`? Why?

Comment: Python is used as a language by a "main" tool (a domain-specific language), and when I use `import` it throws. Note: I am definitely not happy about this.

Comment: Could be an X-Y problem. What error does the import throw? Maybe you should be focusing on getting import to work - it might be as simple as a problem with your environment (paths etc.)